# scaling issue, particles don`t scale down why?

Tags: modeling, rendering, particles

i made this donut from classic blender guru tutorial, i tried to put this into a scene so i appended the model in this scene, now in viewport it is normal but whenever i render the particles above it renders larger. i am using blender 2.82. i have scaled down the donut. particles don`t scale down why? please help[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show me your particle properties

Comment: I tried different thing and now it is working after using collection instance. Now i can scale down model with particles also

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you cannot scale particles you need to scale the particle instance.
In your case most likely you need to scale the cylinder

[image]

Comment: I tried different thing and now it is working after using collection instance. Now i can scale down model with particles also.